# C, What is the difference between unsigned int(a)^unsigned int(b) and unsigned int(a^b)?

Tags: c

In a test platform , I write the program like as below:

```
int a, b;
scanf_s("%d%d",&a,&b);
unsigned int c = a^b;//this can not pass
unsigned int c = unsigned int(a)^unsigned int(b) //this can pass
int cnt = 0;
while (c){
    cnt++;
    c = c&(c-1);
}
printf("%d\n",cnt);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can not pass" ?

Comment: judge on line, it turned out some comment like "time out".But I think it may be indicated that answer is wrong.

Comment: In that case you need to give more detail, e.g. provide a link to the problem statement, otherwise how is anyone supposed to guess what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am sorry ,this is first time to come here.Thank you for your advice. I dont  have the link. The problem is like that"how many binary bits are different bet weent A and B(A,B are both int )"

Comment: In my opinion, the operation "XOR" are the same no matter it is a int or unsigned int. I mean the binary result in the memory.

Comment: The code you show isn't valid C.

Comment: `int(a)` is not allowed in C. You propably are using C++ compiler.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. But I did not get it. you mean difference is cused by the compiler?

Comment: Oh，I get it. I write it on vis2010. The point is whether  the result are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some serious syntax error in your program I doubt it compiled try with the following program and it should work fine.

Following issues were there in your code.

- `c` was declared twice
- casting of `int` to `unsigned int` had a mistake

  ```
  int main()
  {

    int a, b;
    scanf_s("%d%d",&a,&b);
    unsigned int c = a^b;//this can not pass
    c = (unsigned int)a^( unsigned int )b;//this can pass
    int cnt = 0;
    while (c){
        cnt++;
        c = c&(c-1);
    }
    printf("%d\n",cnt);

    return 0; 
  }
  ```

Comment: thank you. I mean that " unsigned int c = a^b " is the same as " c = (unsigned int)a^( unsigned int )b"?  If not ,what is the difference?

Comment: Yes, if your `c` is declared as `unsigned int` and `a,b` are declared as `int` before calling this code. 
Please accept the answer if this solved your query . Thanks !!

Comment: Yes, In my opinion ,they are the same.May be something else cause the code can not pass